# Include commons-net.jar at the custom location instead of ant install location

Tags: ant, apache-commons-net

I am using `ftp` task from `ant`. For `ftp` to work, I need **commons-net.jar** as dependency at

> ANT_HOME/lib folder.

As best practice, I am following the folder structure to keep all external folders under customized External Jars folder. Is there a way to keep **commons-net.jar** at customized folder instead of

> ANT_HOME/lib folder?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to place plugin jars in the "$HOME/.ant/lib" directory.

You can automate the install of your dependent jars as follows:

```
<project name="demo" default="build">

   <available classname="org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP" property="ftp.installed"/>

   <target name="init" unless="ftp.installed">
      <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
      <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/commons-net.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=commons-net/commons-net/3.3/commons-net-3.3.jar"/>
      <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/oro.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=oro/oro/2.0.8/oro-2.0.8.jar"/>
      <fail message="FTP task installed. Run ANT again"/>
   </target>

   <target name="build" depends="init">
      <ftp server="ftp.apache.org" userid="anonymous" password="me@myorg.com">
         <fileset dir="htdocs/manual"/>
      </ftp>
   </target>

</project>
```